# How to programatically remove an option for all cells?

Tags: front-end, options, cells

I'm trying to remove the `CellGroupingRules` options in every cell in a notebook.

Eventually I opened the `Notebook` in a text editor and did a find replace, but there has to be a better solution.

And this doesn't work:

```
Scan[(#=DeleteCases[#, CellGroupingRules, \[Infinity]])&,Cells[]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Does this fit your needs?

```
Scan[
    SetOptions[#, CellGroupingRules -> None] &, 
    Cells[]
]
```

Comment: I tried -> Automatic, but I never tried None, will this break the stylesheet?

Comment: @M.R. I don't know, what do you mean? It should be ok, stylesheet settings are going to be overwritten by this explicit statement so it should be ok. Abount `None`, yes, it was a blind shot :P